# SQL "One to Many" Relationship - Wouldn't a "List of Foreign Keys" be benefitial?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I just recently started using a SQL database for my new project and I have a question regarding one-to-many relationships.

A simplified example: let's say we have a `User` that can define a list of `Persons` (e.g. let's think of a Sims game). Each user just creates their own persons, a person can not be shared between users.

So we have a list of `Users`, each user has a list of `Persons`. I would now represent this in SQL like this (sorry if I don't use any official SQL representing syntax...):

Table Users

```
id: uuid (primary key)
```

Table Persons:

```
owner: uuid (foreign key from `Users`)
number: integer (auto-increment, starting from 0)
primary key: composite of owner and number
name: text
age: integer
gender: text
etc.
```

So now if I want to get a list of all `Persons` that belong to a user, I can simply query the `Persons` table to get all elements where the owner corresponds to the user. Ok.

Now my question: isn't that totally inefficient? I mean, if we have 1 million `Users` that created 10 million `Persons`, the SQL database has to query 10 million `Persons` to find the maybe 5 persons that belong to the current user?

Wouldn't it be more efficient to add a list of persons to the `Users` table, such that the "lookup" can happen faster? E.g. should I update the `Users` table to this?

Table Users

```
id: uuid (primary key)
persons: list of uuid (foreign key from Persons)
```

Table Persons:

```
id: uuid (primary key)
etc.
```

I have seen in all recommendations that the first approach is better and more "SQL" like, but I guess the second approach must be orders of magnitude faster?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `owner` column in your `Person` table will be a foreign key, which in addition to ensuring the relationship will also have an **index**.

Meaning it's super fast and efficient to query the `Person` table filtering on `owner = ...`.

---

Regarding the use of a list of persons in the `User` table, few things:

- list is not a native SQL type
- when it exists, this won't allow foreign key and relationship
- it doesn't scale well: the list will grow with the user, making one user a very large record in terms of storage

Comment: Thanks! I guess that we can simply take as granted that any database is very good at this basic task of looking up a certain index in a table. So trying to "help" by adding the person keys again in the users table would just make everything less maintainable without any benefit!

Comment: @EinGoogle-Nutzer And also worth mentioning the very likely problem of deadlocks when adding and removing and reading happen at the same time. I'd suggest you take the time to read up on [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).